# Keyframe Animation Original Position

Tags: css

I'm very new to animations in CSS, very new indeed. What I'm trying to accomplish is relatively simple conceptually. I want to animate my target element, in which case my background image, back into it's original position.

For example,

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    }
}
```

Would move the background image to it's width, but I'm wondering if it would be possible to animate it back to 0. Otherwise, after reaching it's width, the animation will cut and the background will transition back to 0 instantly, making it seem very choppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be aware, but defining the animation is a lot like creating a function.  You still have to invoke it somewhere.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Hello, Lamb!</title>
    <body>
         <h1>Hello, Lamb!</h1<
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-image: url('http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg');
  background-repeat: none;
  animation: animatedBackground 5s infinite;
}
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    0%{
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    } 
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/BigDaddyTeemoe/pen/qdQdMw

Answer (score 2):

Something like this I think:

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    0%{
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 0;
    } 
    100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
}
```